# Getting a list of field names but unable to access the values from an object

Tags: django, django-views

I am having one issues

One of my function return field names of an model

For example my models.py

```
class Branch( Model):
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    branch_area = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,
        )
```

in my views.py

```
def sample_function(request, id=None):
    query = get_object_or_404(Branch, id=id) if object_id else None
    secured_fields = secured_fields(
        Branch
    )  # This will return the secured fields of that model in the list

    # form example : secured_fields =  ['manager']

    for f in secured_fields:
        print(query.f)
```

It showing an error  'Branch' object has no attribute 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you're doing `query.f` it's not looking for the string value that `f` variable contains but the actual `f` attribute of your model instance.

```
for f in secured_fields:
    print(getattr(query, f, None))
```

---

> `getattr(object, name, default)` 
> Return the value of the named
> attribute of object. **name must be a string.**

Comment: Is there a option to set the value of that attribute as None ....

But there is no need to save that only for dispaly

Comment: If I use setattr it will set permenantly right ? I don't want that ... Only print secured attribute as None

Comment: `setattr` will only set the value of that attribute. It will not save your model instance.